# PyTorch/NumPy: Create binary mask from rgb image

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I have a tensor containing a batch of 4 RGB 128x128 images. So the the tensor has the shape (4,128,128,3). I need to create a binary mask from this tensor where each pixel is black if the image is black and white if the image is not black.
I tried the following `masks = torch.where(image > 0, 1.0, 0.)`. But this way the resulting masks have obviously still three channels. So what's the best way to create a binary mask from a RGB tensor? Same question for numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by applying `sum` along the rgb channels before calling `where`.

```
images_sum = images.sum(axis=3)
masks = torch.where(images_sum > 0, 1.0, 0.)
```